# When does Poincaré inequality hold?

Tags: inequality

Poincaré inequality is given by $$\int_\Omega u^2\le C\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2dx ,$$  where $\Omega$ is bounded open region in $\mathbb R^n$. 
However this inequality is not satisfied by all the function. Take for example a constant function $u=10$ in some region.

Happy to have have some discussions about it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You didn't state the inequality correctly; see here:    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincaré_inequality

Comment: @ChristianBlatter : Sir , i am referring to this link:[http://mathreview.uwaterloo.ca/archive/voli/2/nica.pdf

Comment: In the quoted source the author refers to a certain Sobolev space which is the completion of $C_0^1(\Omega)$. Here the ${}_0$ means that compact support is assumed; in particular these functions vanish on the boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This inequality is, as you have shown by a simple example, not valid as stated. Things can be fixed up in various ways:

In the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality) on the Poincaré inequality it is assumed that the mean value $u_\Omega$ of $u$ on $\Omega$ is zero, resp., the left side of the inequality is replaced by $\int_\Omega|u-u_\Omega|^2\ {\rm d}x$.

In the quoted source the author refers  to a certain Sobolev space which is the completion of $C_0^1(\Omega)$. Here the ${}_0$ means that compact support is assumed; in particular these functions vanish on the boundary.

Comment: @Christain Blatter : Is there any difference to assume that the mean to be zero ?? Is there a special condtion to be applied to assume that the mean is zero ?

Comment: @Theorem: It's an assumption on $u$, namely that $\int_\Omega u\ {\rm d}x=0$. This assumption eliminates your example $u(x)\equiv10$.